# JazzHub Push時のFileサイズの上限について

Tags: bluemix

JazzHub Push 時に、Max object size limit is 104,857,600 bytes のエラーで Push できません。
これを回避するには、こまめに Push する以外に方法はないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

IDS（IBM DevOps Service）のGit仕組みで定められた、Pushできるファイルサイズの上限を超えているため、エラーとなっているようですね。

IDSのオリジナルであるGitの仕組み上、ファイルサイズに制限が有ります。GitHubも同じく、ファイルサイズ50MBを超えるものをPushをすると、Warningが出され、100MBを超えると、Pushできないように制限されています。

IDSでも、104,857,600 bytesにサイズ制限が設定されています。こまめのPushでも良いのですが、チーム開発で100MBを超えるサイズを扱うのは時間がかかると思いますので、ファイルサイズを小さくすることを検討した方がが良いかと思います。